# Add contents of row to table when button is clicked

Tags: php, html, sql, button, mamp

I'm writing a web app using PHP, SQl, and HTML. So far, I can search my Products table using keywords and a query, which displays a HTML table of results. I also have a button 'Favorite' for each row of the HTML table. I want to be able insert a row into my Favorites table when I click the corresponding button.

Columns for my Products table (id, product_name, brands, countries, image_url)

Columns for my Favorites table (id, product_name, brands)

Please disregard id for now if it makes it more confusing. Attached is my code and a screenshot:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkCC2.jpg)

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    try 
    {   
        require "../config.php";
        require "../common.php";

        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

        $sql = "SELECT product_name, brands, countries, image_url 
                FROM Products
                WHERE product_name LIKE :product_name OR brands LIKE :product_name";

        $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];


        if(empty(trim($product_name))) {
            //do nothing
        }
        else {
            $product_name = "%".$product_name."%";
            $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
            $statement->bindParam(':product_name', $product_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $statement->execute();

            $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        }
    }

    catch(PDOException $error) 
    {
       echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
    }
?>
<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

    <h3>Find food product based on keywords</h3>

    <form method="post">
         <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
         <input type="text" id="product_name" name="product_name">
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="View Results">
    </form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php  
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
     if ($result && $statement->rowCount() > 0) 
     { ?>
         <h2>Results</h2>

         <table>
             <thead>
                  <tr>
                       <th>Product Name</th>
                       <th>Brand</th>
                       <th>Countries</th>
                       <th>Image</th>
                 </tr>
             </thead>
        <tbody>
    <?php 
         foreach ($result as $row) 
         { ?>
         <tr>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["product_name"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["brands"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo escape($row["countries"]); ?></td>
            <td><img src="<?php echo escape($row["image_url"]); ?>" alt=""/></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="favorite" value="Favorite"></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
    } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php 
} 
else 
{ ?>
    <blockquote>No results found for <?php echo escape($_POST['product_name']); ?></blockquote>
<?php
    } 
}?> 

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: so... what's not working the way you'd like it to? You didn't say that. You're also not checking for errors.

Comment: *"I want to be able insert a row into my Favorites table when I click the corresponding button."* - There isn't an INSERT statement here.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Your favorites table should have the columns `id, product_id, user_id`. Then you can do a JOIN to get the real product details. Always refrain from duplicating data.

Comment: oh i haven't implemented inserting into Favorites yet, i just dont know where to begin